# How to fix Codeigniter Csrf_token for chrome browser when using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm using **CodeIgniter3** within **Jquery** **Ajax** for inserting some data into database.

However I used ***csrf_token*** to make a security form data when user insert something as below.

**Issue** I not able to insert data into database on Chrome browser but it work in Firefox.

**Errors** ***403 Forbidden*** and

```
<div id="container">
        <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
        <p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>    </div>
</body>
```

This is my Configuration in configure file:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_regeneration'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

And I used controller to insert some data into DB

```
public function post() {

        $new_token = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->ads_m->post_rule);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            echo json_encode(array('res' => FALSE));
        } else {

            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post("p_name"),
                'user_id' => $this->user->user_id(),
                'price' => $this->input->post('p_price'),
                'addr' => $this->input->post('p_add'),
                'des' => $this->input->post('desc'),
                'status' => 1,
            );
            $where = NULL;
            $this->ads_m->insert_post($data, 'ads', $where);
            if ($this->ads_m->insert_check() == TRUE) {
                echo json_encode(array('res' => TRUE, 'token' => $new_token));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('res' => FALSE));
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my model

```
public function insert_post($data, $table, $where = FALSE) {

        $this->db->set($data);
        if ($where) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $this->db->insert($table);
    }
```

**And Here is Ajax for sending data**

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/post'); ?>',
data: $("#post_form").serialize(),
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
beforeSend: function () {
   }, success: function (data) {
          alert("you are successfully ");
   }
 });
}
```

HTML form data

```
 <?PHP echo form_open(base_url('ads/post'),array("class" => "form_horizontal","id" => "post_form")); ?>
  <div class="controls form-group-sm">
    <label class="label-info"> Name </label>
    <?PHP echo form_input('p_name', '', 'class="form-control" id="p_name" '); ?>
    <label class="label-info">Price</label>
    <?PHP echo form_input('p_price', '', 'class="form-control" id="p_prce" '); ?>
    <label class="label-info">Location</label>
    <?PHP echo form_input('p_locat', '', 'class="form-control" id="p_locat" '); ?>
  </div>
 <?PHP echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Oh This code is working as well I forgot to disable my chrome browser cache.so if someone to used you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All **Codeigniter** Developers please note that when you used Ajax to send data and select data from database using CSRF protection please use

```
<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?PHP echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>
```

to valid with you form because when you request to server CSRF protect will check your CSRf to make sure it is equal or not and if Csrf is valid **CI** will let your **Ajax** request.

Here is my last task for adding data into server by using Ajax and Csrf protection and now it is working very well

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
         url: "<?php echo base_url('ads/post'); ?>",
         data: {
         '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?PHP echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
         p_name: $("#p_name").val(),
         p_price: $("#p_price").val(),
         p_addr: $("#p_addr").val(),
         p_des: $("#p_des").val(), 
         p_located: $('#testing option:selected').val(), 
              },
           dataType: "json",
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function () {
               $('#logmodel').modal('show');
               $("#loading_modal").modal({
               backdrop: 'static',
               keyboard: false,
           });
       }, success: function (data) {
            if (data.res === false) {
               $("#m_errors").css({'display': 'inline'});
               $("#loading_modal").modal({
               backdrop: 'static',
               keyboard: false,
             });
           } else {
              $("#loading_modal").modal('hide');
              $('#modalAds').modal('hide');
              $("form input[type=text]").val("");
              $("textarea").val("");
         }
      }
    });
```